# disable selected timeslots using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity

The idea is that the user selects a date from a calendar, available time slots are displayed, and upon selecting an available timeslot, the time slot will be blocked to cancel duplicate timeslot selection, and added to the database.
I am using MVC.NET, WebAPI, EntityFramework and angularJS.

1. my time slots are an array:

   ```
   $("input").click(function () {
       $('.datepicker').pickadate()
       $scope.hours = {};
       $scope.hours = [          
          {
              id: 1,
              name: '12:00'
          },
          {
              id: 2,
              name: '13:00'
          },
          {
              id: 3,
              name: '14:00'
          },
          {
              id: 4,
              name: '15:00'
          },
          {
              id: 5,
              name: '16:00'
          },
          {
              id: 6,
              name: '17:00'
          },
          {
              id: 7,
              name: '18:00'
          },
          {
              id: 8,
              name: '19:00'
          },
          {
              id: 9,
              name: '20:00'
          },
          {
              id: 10,
              name: '21:00'
          },
          {
              id: 11,
              name: '22:00'
          }
        ];});
   ```
2. view is simply retrieve the array with ng-options="hour.name as hour.name for hour in hours".

my questions are:

1. how can i block user selected timeslots using only angular?
2. is it possible to keep the code skinny on the backend, or is it better to sort such things on the server?
3. what way is the most efficient?

Cheers.

Comment: Seems  like a simple property like `available : boolean` is all you need

Comment: hmm i see, so basically i need a scope.$watch on that array, and as it changes value i cancel it out, i understand currently?

Comment: not sure you even need a watch. Presumably you know the timeslot when setting new events

Comment: got it, as long as i have a function that sets availability as bool. i wasnt sure i could do that only using angular! will try it out!